# jQuery Mobile : replace click event by vclick event

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a way to replace all click event by vclick event in jQuery mobile?

The only solution I've found so far is to register a vclick event as below

```
$('a').bind("vclick", function (ev) {
  // Do Some stuff
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is that this solution doesn't prevent jQuery mobile click event to fire so clicks are triggered twice

Comment: Do you want to overwrite click event and store both click and vclick in file?

Comment: I'd like that a click on link triggers the vclick event instead of the regular click event in order to avoid the 300ms delay we observce on touch devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, I got the following to work:

```
$('a').bind('vclick click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   //do some stuff//
 })
```

Without the e.preventDefault() the event fires twice.  With it, it only fires once (but it does fire)

This is similar to what you stated, but may be more all encompassing.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as $('a').bind('click',function(e){ ?

Comment: I don't know.  I can't remember how I got there.  It made sense to me at the time, but now I can't recreate my thinking.   I would say your right, but I think there is some reason the 'solution' works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#elementId").bind('vclick',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
 //your code..
});
```

this is working properly.