# jQuery Mobile vclick fired twice

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an issue with vclick (or click) events when fired.

This is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Document</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <script src="js/cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page">
           <div data-role="header" position="fixed">
            <h1>Data</h1>
           </div>
           <div data-role="content">    
                   <div id="btn_comentar">
                   <a href="#page4"></a>
                   </div>
              </div>
        </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

And this is my functions.js

```
$(document ).bind("mobileinit", function(){

   $(document).bind("pageinit",function(){

       $("#btn_comentar").bind("vclick",function(e){

            console.log(e.isDefaultPrevented());
            console.log(e.result);
            console.log(e.relatedTarget);
            alert("buttooon");

              list_comments();

          });

   });

}
```

When I click my #btn_comentar, the data that I want to retrieve from function list_comments (sending via ajax) is duplicated; I realized that it was sending twice, and finally that it was something about when I clicked on my button.

This is the output from the console (twice):
false
undefined
null

and also the alert message box (twice) "buttoon";

I have tried some solutions like:

[jQuery Mobile : replace click event by vclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364159/jquery-mobile-replace-click-event-by-vclick-event)

but without success, please need some help

**This is my new code and how it is now working, but it seems that without jQuery Mobile's default configuration**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Document</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <script src="js/cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom-mobile.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="page">
               <div data-role="header" position="fixed">
                <h1>Data</h1>
               </div>
               <div data-role="content">    
                       <div id="btn_comentar">
                       <a href="#page4"></a>
                       </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
         </body>
         </html>
```

custom-mobile.js

```
 $(document ).bind("mobileinit", function(){
       //$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;  

      });
```

functions.js

```
$(document).on("ready",function(){
    $("#btn_comentar").bind("vclick",function(){
                  list_comments();
              });
 });
```

Comment: Remove `mobileinit` binding. You can also remove `pageinit` just keep the `vclick` binding. Use `.on` instead of `.bind`.

Comment: Man put your whole html code and everything so I can see how did you structure your html and divs inside

Comment: @Omar thanks, but not working like that

Comment: @abdu I have updated the html code

Comment: Then use jQuery 1.9, jQuery 2.0 will cause problems with JQM 1.3. Also, only `mobileinit` should remain in functions.js, the rest move them after jquery mobile.js.

Answer (score 2):

[According to docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/globalconfig.html),

> These enhancements are applied based on jQuery Mobile's default configuration, which is designed to work with common scenarios, but may or may not match your particular needs. Fortunately, these settings are easy to configure using the `mobileinit` event.

So that's what you need to use `mobileinit` for. For setting defaults like this :

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){
        $.mobile.defaultTransition = 'slideup';
});
```

If my understanding is right, `mobileinit` is included/fired before jQuery Mobile's js is included. Assuming you done that, your script order must look like this :

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script> <!-- This script must have mobileinit -->
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

At this point of time (when custom-scripting.js is loaded), `pageinit` wouldnt be defined.
It would be wise to add your `pageinit` event **AFTER** jQM script.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script> <!-- This script must have mobileinit -->
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
    $(document).bind("vclick", "#btn_comentar" ,function(e){
        console.log(e.isDefaultPrevented());
        console.log(e.result);
        console.log(e.relatedTarget);
        alert("buttooon");
        list_comments();
      });
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks for your interest and help, I did what you said, but with no results, still with the same problem

Comment: I found a solution, but I don't know if its the right one, I made some changes as @hungerpain said, and instead of $(document).bind("pageinit",function(){ ... }); I used $(document).on("ready",function(){ ... }); but as hungerpain said, this is not jQuery Mobile's default configuration..

Comment: @jagudel could you post your code here so tht we could correct that? you're not spsd to use `ready`.

Comment: sorry I'm new here, where should I post my new code? should I update, edit my question or answer it

Comment: Update your question sir. We'll just suggest an alternative to you using ready() event.

Answer (score 1):

use once on pageinit:

```
$(document).on('pageinit') { 
$("#btn_comentar").on("vclick",function(e){

        console.log(e.isDefaultPrevented());
        console.log(e.result);
        console.log(e.relatedTarget);
        alert("buttooon");

          list_comments();

      });
}
```

this should work

Comment: @Omar Enta sa7 , always Thanks

Comment: hala garabti, kol saneh o enta salem :)

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of double-vclicks I've encountered is due to Chromium synthesizing both touch events in addition to mouse events. I confirmed this cause by running the app in desktop Chrome's developer "device mode" (where the mouse cursor changes into a circle), confirming the problem exists, then toggling off device mode, and confirming the problem is "fixed".

[jblas discusses it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1787#issuecomment-1310421), partial excerpt:

> Note that vclick does NOT suppress the synthesized mouse/click events that are generated by the browser because it does not know what context it is being used in, AND form input elements require the mouse/click events to function normally.
>
> If you use a joystick or mouse (desktop), the alert will fire on the normal mouse click event.
>
> If you want to suppress the click event while using touch, you have to call event.preventDefault() in your vclick handler. This will queue the request to kill the click event that follows but due to the differences in the way device vendors implement their events, and some bugs within different android OS versions, this turns out to be very hard to do. We try a couple of methods to figure out whether or not to kill a click event ... one is based on the element the touch event was triggered, on, and another is the position of the touch event. This is necessary because The browser does not necessarily dispatch the mouse events to the same element that it used for the touch event.